# Call a PHP code on form submit - BreezingForms 1.8.2 Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a registration page in Joomla. I use BreezingForms extension for the registration. Everything works fine.

Now,

I want to include my custom PHP code and call a method on form submit. Any advice on how to do ? There is an extension Jumi to include code snippet. But how can I call a particular method on form submit and continue the existing formsubmit operation (that saves in DB).

`<?php
    function WriteContent()
    {
    //My Code
    }
?>`

I want to call the WriteContent on formsubmit.

Here is the Joomla details

Built On: Linux

PHP Version  5.3.18

Joomla! Version  Joomla! 2.5.8 Stable

Joomla Platform 11.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this and basically i paste  the php code on end submit text area

Here is a simple and complex code i use for a site to redirect the form based on k2 extra field oon which the form was published.. The form includes a call to joomla framework. Let me know what you may need and will build you a custom code for that. Hope this is a good direction.

```
require_once("configuration.php");
$conf = new Jconfig ();
$base_url = JURI::root();
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib');
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $state = JRequest::getVar('state');
    $id = JRequest::getVar('id'); 
// Fetch k2 items extra fields
    $f_rows = ff_select("SELECT `extra_fields` FROM  `".$conf->dbprefix."k2_items` WHERE  `id` =".$id);
    $mfields = $f_rows[0];
    $dfields = $mfields->extra_fields;
    $fields =(array)json_decode($dfields,true);

//Blind Method comented assumed item 2 thus in array position 1 is always the redirection link  
    if (isset($fields[1])) {
        $link = @$fields[1]['value'];
                }



        $link = addhttp($link);
        if (url_exists($link)) {JFactory::getApplication()->redirect($link);}


    }// end if isset else go to page 2




//header("location: /index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.cart");

function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}
function url_exists($url) {
    if (!$fp = curl_init($url)) return false;
    return true;
}
```